# Xtext: Difference between production and datatype rule

Tags: parsing, xtext

Can someone explain to me the difference between a production and datatype rule in xtext?
I know so far that both are parser rules and Datatype Rule returns a primitive EDataype and production rule creates an EObject in the AST.. But I can't see a differnce in their grammar definition:

Dataype Rule:
Decimal:
 INT '.' INT
;

Producion Rule:
Model:
  (stats += Statement)*
;

How did the parser know which is what rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parser uses the (inferred) return type of the parser rule to distinguish between productions and data types. If the returned type is an EMF EDataType, the rule is a data type rule, otherwise it's a production rule.

This [blog entry](http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2012/11/xtext-corner-6-data-types-terminals-why.html) tries to highlight some differences between the kinds of rules in Xtext.